# Combine post data before sending

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I've a form on which you can fill in multiple fields. The amount of fields is not fixed, but depended on the user's input.

Simplified form:

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php">
    Field one: <input type="text" name="field[]" /><br />
    Field two: <input type="text" name="field[]" /><br />
    Field three: <input type="text" name="field[]" /><br />

    <br /><br />

    Checkbox one: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1" /><br />
    Checkbox two: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1" /><br />
    Checkbox three: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1" /><br />

    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem I'm facing, is that `field one` should be paired with `checkbox one`, `two` with `two` and so on. This doesn't sound to hard, right? If everything is checked and filled in, it's not:

```
Array
(
    [field] => Array
        (
            [0] => one 
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
        )

    [check] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

In PHP I could just link the array indexes together and all is well. The problem I'm facing, is when you don't select the second checkbox. If you do that, there will be one entry less in the `check post data`:

```
Array
(
    [field] => Array
        (
            [0] => one 
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
        )

    [check] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

What is the best way to handle this situation? Ajax submitting isn't an option, but JavaScript manipulation is.

*I was thinking of some way to create arrays in JS per element (one, two, three) and submit that data. The question is, how should I do that, or is there an better (nicer) way to handle this problem?*

Comment: maybe hidden text field for check boxes. if the check box checked, hidden field get value, if not, hidden field be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pair them up with matching indexes and set a default hidden input for the checkbox BEFORE defining it:

```
Field one:    <input type="text" name="field[0]" /><br />

              <input type="hidden" name="check[0]" value="0">
Checkbox one: <input type="checkbox" name="check[0]" value="1" /><br />
```

So now you always have a `check[0]` matched with `field[0]` but it will have value `0` if not checked.

Comment: I've been working to long on this, that's for sure... Of course adding an index is the best solution, and will work. that I didn't thought of it by myself...

Comment: And thank you for coming up with that neat little trick for the checkboxes... Never knew that was possible.